# How do I run an npm script of a dependent package

Tags: npm

I have a package that itself has a script in its `package.json` that I would like to be able to run in my top-level project. This package is one of my top-level projects dependencies. I'm looking for a way to directly or indirectly call the dependency packages script.

Let us assume the module name I'm working with is named `foo` and the script I want to run is `updateFooData`.

I tried using the syntax `npm run-script <package> <...>` to run it, but this appears to be deprecated functionality as I can't find it in the current [official documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) but I see it in other (very old) search results.

```
npm run-script foo updateFooData

# npm ERR! missing script: foo
```

I also looked into the npm api and while `npm.commands.run-script(args, callback)` will do what I want, I can't figure out how to load the module into npm

```
{
  ...
  "scripts":{
    "foo:updateFooData": "node --eval \"... ??; npm.commands.run-script('updateFooData', callback)\""
  }
}

npm run foo:updateFooData
# Obviously fails
```

The only thing I've found that works so far is to CD into the submodule directory and run npm from there. This is not the preferred solution for me.

```
cd node_modules/foo
npm run updateFooData
```

Answer (score 39):

I ran into this trying to run the updatedb script for geoip-lite. You should use the [npm explore command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/explore) which will spawn a new shell in a dependencies' directory.

So for your use case, try `npm explore foo -- npm run updateFooData`

Comment: Copy-paste: `npm explore geoip-lite -- npm run updatedb`

Comment: As a cautionary note, this does not work for windows https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8932

Comment: amazing, came here looking to automate updating geoip-lite and learnt about the explore command.

Answer (score -1):

Note:

> This isn't a very good idea. You have no guarantee which node_modules folder module will be installed in as NPM will attempt to optimise space by installing shared packages at the highest level possible. – @superluminary

---

Something I've found that does work:

If the script you are running runs a script file, you can look at the path of the file it's running and run the script using a require:

```
# if node_modules/foo/package.json looks like this
{
  "scripts": {
    "updateFooData":"scripts/updateFooData.js"
  }
}

# then package.json can look like this
{
  "scripts": {
    "foo:updateFooData":"node --eval \"require('foo/scripts/updateFooData.js')\""
  }
}

# or package.json can look like this
{
  "scripts": {
    "foo:updateFooData":"node node_modules/foo/scripts/updateFooData.js"
  }
}

# and you can run it like this
npm run foo:updateFooData
```

I don't like this solution because it only works if the npm script you are running is a file. It won't apply in all

Comment: This isn't a very good idea. You have no guarantee which node_modules folder module will be installed in as NPM will attempt to optimise space by installing shared packages at the highest level possible.

Comment: I think that wasn't true when I wrote this solution, but it is true now. Thanks for the info.