# Running a script inside package.json under node_modules?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, yarnpkg

I am used to run `yarn` / `npm` and then the command:

```
yarn build-me
```

or

```
npm run build-me
```

This calls a **script command** declared in the the local `package.json` root file.

In my case I'd like to **run a script command** declared in the `package.json` of a package in `node_modules` folder.

How can I do this?

I have installed a test package i wrote inside app. Here is the dependency (in my root app) and I can see it under node_modules

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@tester/util-package": "^1.0.2"
  }
```

Under node_modules this util-package also has it's own package.json with the following script

```
  "scripts": {
    "process-files": "node ./cli.js"
  },
```

So, I was hoping to run this from the root of my app something like.

```
yarn util-package process-files
```

Of course, this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run an npm script of a dependent package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989972/how-do-i-run-an-npm-script-of-a-dependent-package)

Answer (score 17):

If you want to run a command inside a submodule, with *npm*, you can use the `explore` command, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36861740/5156280):

`npm explore submodule -- npm run subscript`

It seems that *yarn* does not have an equivalent command,
but there is a `cwd` option (not yet very well [documented](https://github.com/yarnpkg/website/pull/774)) that let you choose the working directory:

`yarn --cwd node_modules/submodule/ subscript`

Comment: Note that the module is maybe not located under `node_modules` when you are using workspaces and the path used with the `--cwd` option must be adapted. n this case `npm explore` is the more versatile solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`explore`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/explore) command:

`npm explore @tester/util-package -- npm run process-files`