# Run a npm bin script from a dependencies package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to create 2 seperate packages - the first should only have `package-2` as a dependency and `package-2` can have anything required for that package.

My problem is that one of the `dependencies` in `package-2` (let's call it `package-3`) has a bin script. I'd like to expose that for `package-1` to use but it's not work.

When running `npm run start` in package 1 I get the following error:

`./bin/sh package-3 is not a command`

```
{
  "name": "package-1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "package-2 start",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "package-2": "1.0.0",
  }
}
```

```
{
  "name": "package-2",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "package-3 start",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "package-3": "1.0.0",
  }
}
```

```
{
  "name": "package-3",
  "bin" : {
    "package-3": "cli-with-start-command",
  },
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989972/how-do-i-run-an-npm-script-of-a-dependent-package

Comment: Maybe under the bin: "package-3": "node_modules/.bin/package-3" could do?