# Run script that is in package.json of a dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, package

I have this app structure:

```
root
  whatever
  node_modules
    module_A
      package.json
```

The package.json of module_A has some scripts. Let's say:

```
"scripts": {
  "first_script": whatever
}
```

How to run first_script from the terminal?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989972/how-do-i-run-an-npm-script-of-a-dependent-package

Comment: Thanks. I did not find that question.

I am going to mark my own question as duplicate. However, I ask an admin to review the messy question and answers from (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989972/how-do-i-run-an-npm-script-of-a-dependent-package) against the simplicity of this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is:

```
npm explore module_A -- npm run first_script
```