# Defining Typescript types for my own code in a different folder

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a library where I want to autogenerate Typescript types for the user's code. For that I would love to put the type definitions in a different folder, so that they are out of sight, but the IDE can still pick them up.

This is possible with Typescript modules, but I couldn't find a way to define types for an "ambient" module. A simplified code example for how I would like the file structure to be:

```js
    // src/pages/WelcomePage.ts
    export const message = 'hi'
```

```js
    // src/index.ts
    import { message } from './pages/WelcomePage'
    console.log(message) // message should be of type "Message", not of type "string".
```

```js
    // types/pages/WelcomePage.d.ts
    // This doesn't work.
    // Can we make it work somehow?
    declare module "pages/WelcomePage" {
        type Message = string
        export const message: Message
    }
```

tldr: I would like all my generated types to be in `types/...` and they should define types for `src/...`.

Comment: Do you already have the algorithm to generate _the code itself_ for `.d.ts` files? Or is this something you want us to help you with (in addition to the configuration-related question)?

Comment: Also, do you use path aliases in your project? If you do, this might help

Comment: Thanks for the questions. Generating the .d.ts files is no problem, I just need to find out how I can make this work in general, really implementing it so the code gets generated automatically is no problem.

Comment: It would be possible to use path aliases in general, but not for all files, because there could potentially be hundreds of pages like the "src/pages/WelcomePage.ts" example

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working using path aliases combined with following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53014974/8456680

My solution using the "transformers" variant from said answer, combined with `@` as alias for `src` directory:

```
// src/pages/WelcomePage.ts
export const message = "aaa";
```

```
// src/index.ts
import { message } from "@/pages/WelcomePage"
console.log(message)
```

```
// types/pages/WelcomePage.d.ts
declare module "@/pages/WelcomePage" {
    type Message = string
    export const message: Message
}
```

And project setup:
`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["src/*"]
        },
        "plugins": [
            {
                "transform": "@zerollup/ts-transform-paths",
                "exclude": ["*"]
            }
        ]
    },
    "include": ["./types/**/*", "./src/**/*"]
}
```

`package.json`

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "ttsc -p ."
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@zerollup/ts-transform-paths": "^1.7.18",
        "ttypescript": "^1.5.13",
        "typescript": "~4.4.0"
    }
}
```

How does it work? The declaration files are included first, resulting in declaration of `@/pages/WelcomePage` module, which is then used by TS for checking during import in `index.ts`.

During compilation the `ts-transform-paths` is executed and rewrites the path `@/pages/WelcomePage` to resolved `./pages/WelcomePage` making sure the resulting code works.

This solution however has a drawback: Noone is checking if `src/pages/WelcomePage.ts` actually exports what `types/pages/WelcomePage.d.ts` says it does.

Comment: With path aliases no plugins are needed

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky Could you please explain why they are not? In my testing without any plugins the resulting (emitted) code had the following:
```var WelcomePage_1 = require("@/pages/WelcomePage");
```
This however led to the code not being runnable by Node.js as it couldn't find the required file.

Comment: Sorry for the bad wording, by "plugins" I meant "transformers". The usual choice to enable aliases at runtime is [`tsconfig-paths`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) package – everything that's required for the job is encapsulated in `--require tsconfig-paths/register`

Comment: @Moritur But the general direction in this answer is similar to what I wanted to suggest (hence the question in the comments). Give it a try.

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky While I do like `tsconfig-paths`, if one is making a library/package it might not be viable option as it would then require all dependants to use it as well, while transformer allows to use with plain node after build step (which is the usual environment packages are used in)

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions and the sample code! I will give this a shot, even though I'm not sure that the DX will be good enough, because this forces all imports to use the `@` prefix which might not be feasible in all circumstances. Nevertheless this is an interesting path worth following further. I'd still like to keep this open in case someone else has a "more native" way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am not understanding the question fully, but this seems like something that could be done with a custom tsconfig and npm command.  The tsconfig specifies the input and output directories, as well as that you only want declaration files:

```js
// tsconfig.special.json:

{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "compiler_options": "go_here",
        "emitDeclarationOnly": true, // will only emit .d.ts files
        "outDir": "types"
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

So all .ts files within the src directory will be compiled through typescript, but only .d.ts files will be emitted (not actual js), and they will end up in the `types` directory.

Now your npm command under "scripts" might look something like this:

```
"compile": "tsc --p tsconfig.special.json"
```

You said this is a library that other developers will install.  If that's the case, they will have to create their own npm script to run this one.  How to do that is discussed in [How do I run an npm script of a dependent package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989972/how-do-i-run-an-npm-script-of-a-dependent-package).

You may need to tweak your tsconfig to make sure the `src` folder that typescript is reading from is indeed the `user_project/src`, not `user_project/node_modules/your_library/src`. If you want the library user's ide to pick up the newly generated declarations, the same goes for the output dir.  It needs to output to `user_project/types`, not `user_project/node_modules/your_library/types`.  If you need help accounting for that in your tsconfig / npm command, please make a comment and I can elaborate.  Your use may also need to be informed that they will need to add the generated `/types` directory to *their project's* tsconfig.json, so make sure the generated .d.ts files are picked up.

Hopefully I'm not totally off the mark on what you're asking.

Comment: If I understand what you are suggesting correctly, you are actually misunderstanding the question :/ I want to have type definitions for user defined code which supersede the actual types that the user defined code contains. Actually creating those type definitions is not a problem.